# If $H\trianglelefteq G$ and$P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ then $\gcd([H: H\cap P], p)=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group, $H\trianglelefteq G$ and $P$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. How can I show $$\gcd([H: H\cap P], p)=1?$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H\cap P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $H$. Let $Q$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$ containing $H\cap P$. Then $Q\le P'$ for some (possibly different) $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. But $P$ and $P'$ are conjugate, say $P=gP'g^{-1}$. Then $gQg^{-1}=g(H\cap P')g^{-1} = gHg^{-1}\cap gP'g^{-1}=H\cap P$, i.e. $H\cap P$ is already a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$.